# How can I use only coloring of pip-requirements mode?

Tags: coloring, pip-requirements

I am using https://github.com/Wilfred/pip-requirements.el to view my requirements.txt file. Coloring pattern is simple where: `<pip_package_name>==<0.0.0>`  ; pip package name and its version number is in different colors.

But when I open requirements.txt file and  `pip-requirements` is running as a major mode it freezes my machine since it only has 1 GiB RAM, which usually forces emacs to restarted. I believe `pip-requirements` does some memory hungery operation on the background.

Is it possible to use only coloring of `pip-requirements.el` mode provide and disable any other operation that runs on the backgorund.

Comment: The package you use depends on ```auto-complete``` package, as described in function ```pip-requirements-auto-complete-setup```, so your Emacs freezes since this package is not found. Decide yourself about that.

Comment: I have installed it using `M-x install auto-complete` but freezing still continues

Comment: Now you have another problem(s) - auto-complete may conflicts with company, requested also by lsp - try step by step, do not use your init.el, but just only auto-complete, pip-requirements.el and see if it is freezing (in a new init.el test file). If you have a machine with small ram, adding such package as pip-requirements may not worth the effort.